# PHP Hashed Master Passwords in Code

Tags: php, security, hash, passwords

I'm developing a PHP web application that uses an LDAP server for authentication. However, in case the LDAP server goes down, or something else goes wrong and I still need to access the system, I want to have a master password written directly in the code.

The previous iteration of this system (which I did not write) simply stored the passwords as plaintext (!). So:

```
if ($username == "dan" && $password == "32fsss") {
```

which of course is extremely unsecure.

So I want to fix that. I was thinking of hashing the password, so doing

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password);
if ($username == "dan" && $hashedPassword == "HASHPASSWORDSTOREDHERE") {
```

So I would hard-code the *hash* for the master password, not the actual password itself. Is this secure? I know a stolen hash is bad, but it's better than a stolen plaintext password.

Of course all user-input would be appropriately sanitized.

Alternatively: any other thoughts for having a master-password access system?

Comment: If the user is looking at the source to find the hash then they can probably just change the source to let themselves in regardless... However, yes comparing to the hash is a bit more secure since it wont give out the actual password you may be using, that may be used elsewhere

Comment: If someone has access to view the PHP code there is something wrong. So them seeing an unhashed password is the least of your issues. If you want you could store the password in a file that is not inside your www directory.

Comment: If the hash gets you access, it's just as good as a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's purely a read only incident and all they get is the hashed version, it shouldn't be an issue. That being said, I prefer to use the `hash()` function rather than `password_hash()`, but that's just my personal preference.

The only issue is if the attacker who reads the php file and obtains the hashed password has a way to reverse it (i.e. a rainbow table). In this instance, your system becomes insecure. This is where my preference for `hash()` over `password_hash()` comes from. With `hash()`. To generate the hashed form, I can say:

```
$HashedMasterPassword = hash('md5', $MasterPassword . "MyMD5Salt") . hash('sha256', $MasterPassword . "MyShaSalt");
```

Then in my uploaded code I can take the output of the above code (`$HashedMasterPassword`) and hard code that string into my code. This adds two different salts, two different hashing functions and it reduces the already low chance of a rainbow table attack because the attacker would need a collision that occurs for both md5 + the first salt and sha256 + the second salt. This is, I dare say the word, impossible. Sure, pigeon hole effect says it's possible and it is, but this is SO near impossible that I wouldn't fret over it.

That all said, using `password_hash()` and storing that hash is fine if you really want to. I just personally dislike it.

**EDIT: ADDING ON IMPLEMENTATION DETAILS**

I believe based on the comments that there was some confusion as to how this would be implemented. Let's say my master password was `thisIsMyPassword` (Super secret and super secure, I know). Well, we'd need to generate the hard coded hashed form. The hard coded hashed form would be found by saying:

```
$MasterPassword = "thisIsMyPassword";
$HashedMasterPassword = hash('md5', $MasterPassword . "MyMD5Salt") . hash('sha256', $MasterPassword . "MyShaSalt");
echo $HashedMasterPassword;
```

**Important:** You would NOT upload this to the server. This would just be used for generating the hash and it should then be permanently deleted.

The output of this would be: `6dcfc45fba2fff44b7cfc8df7245a1b7804c88d63a82ac2ba33e0de32ab7f20c5afe2c1784e87f1bae8a4f91f1a84833`

So, in your code that requires a master password to override, you'd enter:

```
$MasterHash = '6dcfc45fba2fff44b7cfc8df7245a1b7804c88d63a82ac2ba33e0de32ab7f20c5afe2c1784e87f1bae8a4f91f1a84833';
$SubmittedMasterPass = $_POST['MasterPassword'];
$HashedVersionOfSubmittedMasterPass = hash('md5', $SubmittedMasterPass . "MyMD5Salt") . hash('sha256', $SubmittedMasterPass . "MyShaSalt");
if($MasterHash !== $HashedVersionOfSubmittedMasterPass){
  die('Override Failed. Reason: Wrong Password.');
}else{
  // User has successfully logged in using the master password.
}
```

Again to clarify based on information from the comments, this is more secure than just using SHA256 because a brute-forced master password must be found that produces `6dcfc45fba2fff44b7cfc8df7245a1b7` when `MyMD5Salt` is appended to the end of it and it also must produce `804c88d63a82ac2ba33e0de32ab7f20c5afe2c1784e87f1bae8a4f91f1a84833` when `MyShaSalt` is appended onto the end of it. This means the collision must satisfy two different algorithms which is much more difficult to do than satisfying just the Sha256 algorithm on it's own.

However, as noted in the comments, this does take a few more milliseconds to process; so, if decreasing execution time is a big priority to you, then it might be recommended to only use Sha256 on its own rather than using MD5 and Sha256 combined.

Comment: Wow, that's really secure (your concatenated has). But why bother with the md5? Is not SHA safe enough already? Or just because you can, for added redundancy?

Comment: Sha256 is already VERY secure, but hey, if taking another few milliseconds isn't an issue, then I always promote adding some more security. For bonus security, even use a SHA512 in place of the SHA256. It does take the script another few milliseconds to execute, but that's usually not bad. My real job actually deals quite a bit (no pun intended) with cryptography and properly storing processed files without storing files more than once. As such, we use both SHA256 and MD5 as both are extremely fast and it is nearly impossible to have a planned or accidental collision if you use both together.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak - Since the only reasonable way for cracking a single SHA256 hash is brute-forcing, a double hash will not increase security, it's just calculating 2 hashes instead of one. Actually one can argue that you narrow down the possibilities of SHA256 with calculating a MD5 first. Instead the time to calculate a single hash-value is important, the longer the more difficult to brute force.

Comment: I see what you're saying when you say, "narrow down the possibilities," but I beg to differ with your opinion on that matter. While yes, calculating a collision for MD5 is easier than SHA256, really both require brute forcing because the MD5 portion would use a salt and thus by using a salt (assuming the salt is very unique) the MD5 portion would not exist in a rainbow table with the salt. I'll add onto my answer with some additional code that should clarify how this would be implemented.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak - I see that with your code you can prevent the usage of collisions for login. But to find the _original_ password an attacker can brute-force solely with MD5 now. The weaker algorithm defines the security of the hash. Rainbow-tables are only useful to crack several hashes at once, not for a single one.

Comment: You are entirely wrong about the use of a rainbow table. Yes, they can be helpful with many hashes, but you can simply enter one into a rainbow table as well. Anyway, assuming a unique salt is used and the master password is more than something simple like "password", it is unlikely that a brute-force attack would be fruitful. In fact because the MD5 digest is smaller than Sha256, a collision on MD5 would be easier than brute-forcing back to the original password. MD5 exacerbates the pigeonhole effect compared to sha256. There is more data loss using MD5 and it's less unique.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak - Nobody will generate a whole rainbow-table to crack a single password (assuming a salt was used at all), after finding a match there is no need to continue the search, this you would do when building a rainbow-table (brute-forcing is faster). A salt does not help at all against brute-forcing a single password, it is not secret. It depends entirely on the strongness of the password if you first find the original password or a collision. With 8 Giga MD5 hashes per second you can test a whole english dictionary in less than a milli second!

Comment: @martinsoeckli Nobody said the salt is a secret, but if the password is long and a completely random character mix (as you suggested in your answer), then a brute-force attack might turn back many "correct" results which are not actually accurate. Also, one could (and typically should) use a preexisting, public rainbow table rather than only generating their own. Regardless, I'm sure we're not supposed to debate in the comments and I will continue to stand by my answer. I see where you're coming from, but I disagree that this makes it less secure.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has access to the source code. They can just change it, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I was thinking of accidental read. If somebody has write access, then they can just bypass the entire authentication.

Answer (score 0):

One can discuss if such a "backdoor" is desirable or not, but if you cannot decide it for yourself, there are two ways to protect such a hardcoded password. Storing only the hash is surely much better than the plaintext password, because everybody with read-access to the code could otherwise use it on a running system.

The first possibilty is to use a slow hash algorithm with a cost factor, such as `password_hash()` which you proposed in your example. If an attacker has read-access to the code, he would have to brute-force this password, to use it on a live system. A slow hash algorithm will thwart brute-forcing, while MD5 and other functions are ways too fast ([8 Giga MD5 per second](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance)). The drawback is a slowdown in your application when the password is verified.

The second possiblity is a very strong password. Choose a long enough random combination, e.g. 70 characters generated with a password-manager and use it as the master key. Even fast algorithms like SHA256 are out of scope for brute-forcing then, and your key is immune against dictionary attacks and does not even need salting.